# external link in a table with DataTables (a plug-in for jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html-table, datatables, hyperlink

I have a table [here](http://trovawiki.altervista.org/english_resources.php) which is built using a JSON file and DataTables (a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library).
The table can be filtered and the plug-in works.

The cells in the first column contain a link to an external website, which opens in a different tab (I used `target="_blank"`).
When I apply filter to the table, its rows are filtered correctly but as I click on a link **all filters are reset and the entire table is shown**.

Any tips to work around this?

Comment: Have you added `stateSave: true` to your DataTable? You can see an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61691054/12567365), which also uses filter panes (although the question is for a different scenario than yours).

Comment: Thanks. I've added `stateSave: true` as shown [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) but the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a small bug in the previous repository of DataTables.
Following [this discussion](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/64545/issue-with-link-to-external-page), I solved the issue by using the latest release of the pug-in.
Now the links in the first column do not cause the entire table to redraw.